# CF query result reference in JS?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

How do I reference a coldfusion query's result in a javascript function?

```
<CFQUERY name ="getPin" datasource = "pins">
SELECT pin
FROM pinuser
where email="#getEmail#"
</cfquery>
```

I want to set the pin, as a JavaScript variable called `pincode`, I tried:

```
var <cfoutput>#ToScript(#pin#,"pincode")#;</cfoutput>
```

then

```
alert(pincode)
```

but it doesnt work, any ideas?

Comment: You're using two sets of pound signs. This is your error. Check out my example for you below.

Comment: You should consider using `<cfqueryparam>` for `#getEmail#` in your `where` clause. You'll get SQL injection attack protection, plus query plan caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script type="javascript" language="text/javascript">
  <cfoutput>
    var pincode = '#getPin.pin#';
    alert(pincode);
  </cfoutput>
</script>
```

I would also include a "top 1" in the SQL or maxrows=1 in the cfquery tag, unless the email is the primary key of the table or otherwise has a unique constraint.

Comment: I believe that your answer would work, but the question was how to best use the ColdFusion function toScript();  You've got good advice about the query stuff though!

Comment: In addition, it might not work if the query value contained special characters like single quotes. `ToScript` escapes any special characters, avoiding that problem. Also if you need to limit the records, I would go with `TOP` (or `LIMIT`, ...) over `maxrows`. `TOP` limits the data *before* it is returned to CF. So it is more efficient.

Comment: Actually, the question was, "How do I reference a coldfusion query's result in a javascript function?" and it was stated that you had tried the toScript() function. I've not looked too much into that function, so I just answered what I knew. It does sound like a useful function, though. I don't usually have too much call to include server side data in client side scripts. I'll certainly keep it in mind, though.

Answer (score 3):

It's really simple, and useful:

```
<script>
    <cfoutput>#toscript(getPin.pin, "JSVariableName")#</cfoutput>
</script>
```

Your output should be something like this:

```
<script>
    var JSVariableName = 12345; // 
</script>
```

Comment: Another nugget of truth in your answer is that it's also crucial to reference the cfquery result properly: getPin.pin and not just pin

Comment: If my answer is the correct answer, please select it as such. If you need more information, please edit your question so that I can help you.  Thanks!